# Flot charting library: show points on line chart only on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, flot

Using the flot library, how can I show the point only when hovering over that spot on the line? I don't want all dots visible all the time..

Similar to how google does it: See the first example: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

Can't use google since I need to combine multiple chart types. I also like that with google you don't have to hover over the exact point, close enough and the tooltip is triggered as well.

Can flot do this? Or any other libraries?

Edit: these guys appear to be using flot, but I'm not sure how they do it? https://www.portfolionumbers.com/tools/risk/report

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the option object you can specify something like:

```
{
    series: { lines: { show: true }, points: { show: false } },
    grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: false }
}
```